# How to put a Dynamic-/VBA-generated Range into a Cell's Formula?

Tags: excel

Say we have this code

```
Dim runningTotal As Range

reference = Range("A4").Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(7).Range("A:JL").FormatConditions.Delete ' Delete current scales

For Each c In Worksheets("PVP Calculator").Range("A7:JL1506").Cells
 '   If c.Interior.colorIndex <> 0 Then
  '      c.Interior.colorIndex = 0
   ' End If
    If c.Value = reference Then
'       c.Interior.colorIndex = 6
        If runningTotal Is Nothing Then
            Set runningTotal = c
        Else
            Set runningTotal = Union(runningTotal, c)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

How do I make the cell B4 display the maximum value in the range runningTotal? Doing something like `Range("B4").Value = MAX(runningTotal)` doesn't work.

(The cells are equal at first, but then I change another cell to make the rest of the sheet have different values. Additionally, I plan to change `c.Value = reference Then` into a tolerance, I think with this? `c.Value >= reference-5 And c.Value <= reference+5 Then`)

Thanks in advance. I've spent half the day failing to use the right keyword searches and browsing MSDN to figure out how to do what I want.

Comment: It should be `Range("B4").Value = Application.Max(runningTotal)`

Comment: I got my answer, as I continued the search after submitting the question. It was `Range("B4").Formula = "=MAX(" & runningTotal.Address & ")"`. I failed in the & concatenation at first, and overlooked Address until now.

Your suggestion unfortunately results in a static value in the cell, which isn't what I want. Thanks though for teaching me to prefix with Application. before calling a "standard" function, for lack of a better term.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer, as I continued the search after submitting the question. It was `Range("B4").Formula = "=MAX(" & runningTotal.Address & ")"`. I failed in the & concatenation at first, and overlooked the Address property until now